# Laravel multiple route parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to create a route that lets me download a file when given its path:

```
example.com/download/dogs/beagles/stickypaw.jpg
example.com/download/dogs/germanshepards/woofer.jpg
example.com/download/dogs/alldogs.jpg
```

Normally I would use named parameters,
however in this case that would mean having 3 different routes:

```php
Route::get('/download/package}/{folder}/{filename}',function ($package, $folder,$filePath) {
  $filePath = "$package/$folder/$filePath";
  return Storage::download($filePath);    
});

Route::get('/download/{package?}/{filename}', function ($package, $filePath) {
  $filePath = "$package/$filePath";
  return Storage::download($filePath);
});

Route::get('/download/{filename}', function ($filename) {     
  return Storage::download($filename);
});
```

Is there a way to get the path after download into a variable?

example:

```php
Route::get('/download/{path}', function ($path) {
   // loop over the path array
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tested, but should work:

```
Route::get('/download/{path}', function ($path) {     
    $folders = explode('/', $path);

    // ...
})
    ->where('path', '(.+)');
```